# Convert Entry<String, List<String>> to Entry<String, String>

Tags: java, http

I am trying to store the header name and it's first value as an Entry into a list. I am not sure how to achieve this.

```
HttpHeaders headerNames = request.getHeaders();
List<Entry<String, String>> reqHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headerNames.entrySet()) {
    reqHeaders.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(0));   //This line is incorrect
}
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from **Java 9,** there is a new utility method allowing to create an **immutable** entry which is [`Map#entry(Object, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-).

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headerNames.entrySet()) {
     reqHeaders.add(Map.entry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(0)));  
}
```

For before **Java 9**, you can use [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html) or [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headerNames.entrySet()) {
    reqHeaders.add(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(0))); // immutable
    reqHeaders.add(new SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(0))); // mutable version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this, but @azro answer is simpler.

```
        HttpHeaders headerNames = request.getHeaders();
        Map<String, String> headersMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Entry<String, String>> requestHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headerNames.entrySet()) {
            headersMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(0));
        }
        requestHeaders.addAll(headersMap.entrySet());
```